# Link Gestures to Reload UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to get a gesture to reload a webpage for an app I am coding for. As of now the gestures are working by using `UIGestureRecognizer`. I have successfully been able to code such that when I swipe I have a `UILabel` change. I want to use this gesture to reload a webpage. Currently, I have something like this in my m file that causes this to happen.

```
- (void)ScreenWasSwiped
{
    [swipe setText:@"This is working"];
}
```

and under `viewdidload`

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipedown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector (ScreenWasSwiped)];
swipedown.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipedown.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipedown];
```

How can I change this so that I can reload the browser with the same gesture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method called `ScreenWasSwiped`, use call `reload` on your UIWebView instance. It'll look something like this:

```
-(void)ScreenWasSwiped
{
    [myWebView reload];
}
```